# Google Flex App Engine Java : cron job returning status 499

Tags: java, cron, app-engine-flexible

I have a job running every 5 minutes, and 10 times a day, cron is returning a status 499, but the job is still running (based on my trace in the log).  Cron starts a new job, which then overlaps with the previous job that was not completed yet.

In the standard environment, you can set the  , but it is not available in the standard environment.  I would have set it to a long enough interval for the job to complete.

What could be causing the 499 ? Some old post mentioned running out of memory(I had no outofmemory error), I added 2 Gb to my configuration and I am still having the error.

MartinIT